# How to check if numeric textbox is empty?

Tags: java, android

I'm Starting to learn Android Studio java, i'm on basics yet.
Im doing an simple exercice i found on youtube "adding two numbers simple calculator". 
I finished it and im trying to improve it by myself but im having trouble, if i let one of the EditTextBox empty the app crash, so i'm trying to check if the EdidTextbox is empty.
I Searched here and tried all thing and none works, or the code give error, or the one it works simple keep crashing. tried using some String to get de value and then check but wont work. (the one it's commented)
Just want a simple check in the editText if its empty just tell me error.
help please. thanks!

Code:

```
 public void OnButtonClick(View ver) {
        EditText et1 = findViewById(R.id.et1);
        EditText et2 = findViewById(R.id.et2);
        TextView tv1 = findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        float num1 = Float.parseFloat(et1.getText().toString());
        float num2 = Float.parseFloat(et2.getText().toString());
        //String input = et1.getText().toString();
        //String input2 = et2.getText().toString();
        if ( TextUtils.isEmpty(et1.getText().toString()) ) {
            et1.setError("Error");

        }
            else {
            et1.setError("Ok");
        }
        float sum = num1 + num2;
        tv1.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the documentation of the numeric textbox, this kind of function must exist, if not try setting an default value.

Comment: Normally if you want to check if string or int is empty, I would either use equal to nothing (variable.gettext.tostring == "") or length of the variable below 0 (variable.length <= 0)

Comment: @Nero et1.length()<= 0 didnt work, i insert 0 says ok, i leave it empty and app crash and exit.

Comment: You are checking the length of what the user put in with that condition. You are not checking the value. If u want to check the value, you will need to convert it to int 
Int myvalue = edittext.gettext or int myvalue = int.valueof(edittext.gettext)
And then use the condition to compare the int value (myvalue <= 0)
Please note I am typing from phone so I don't know exact syntax

Comment: I tried:int myvalue = Integer.getInteger(et1.getText().toString());
int myvalue = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
int myvalue = Integer.valueOf(et1.getText().toString());
and then compared ( myvalue <= 0  ) and still app crash if i leave it empty and exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a try catch clause instead of if like this

```
    public void OnButtonClick(View ver) {
        EditText et1 = findViewById(R.id.et1);
        EditText et2 = findViewById(R.id.et2);
        TextView tv1 = findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        float num1;
        float num2;
        try
        {   

            num1 = Float.parseFloat(et1.getText().toString());
            num2 = Float.parseFloat(et2.getText().toString());
            float sum = num1 + num2;
            tv1.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
            et1.setError("Ok"); 

        }catch(NullPointerException e){ 

            et1.setError("Error");
        }   

    }
```

But is just a approach you cant try another different. This catch clause it is only for null point exceptions, but imagine if its something different like division by 0, you can try another clause. Please read this [article](http://java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=293)

Comment: Okay i managed to do it with try, i did some errors first pretty dumb way you were right. works 100% ty bro

Answer (score 2):

Solution:The below statement will return true
if EditText remains empty

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(et1.getText()) {
   // enter your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First implement TextWatcher in your class.
Then use this to check if your textfield is empty or not.

```
if(et1.getText().toString().lenghth()==0){
et1.setError("This Field cannot be empty");
}
```

Comment: didn't work, i left edittext 1 empty and clicked on the button, app crashed and exit. :(

Answer (score 0):

So you want to check  the editText field is empty or not,you have to check that when user press "add" button.
you do it this way:

```
if (!etEmail.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                //the editbox is not empty
              //do what ever you want
            } else
                etEmail.setError("the edit box is empty");
```

**Update** full code:

```
addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!etText.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                //do what ever you want
               Integer sum = text1 + text2;
            } else
                etBox.setError(getText(R.string.noEmail));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: didnt work too, when i leave the edittext empty app crash and exit.

Comment: send me the Logcat

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, like exe said i used a try catch and it worked, im gonna read the article for some try catch info since im  more familiar with if's.
the if didnt work in any way, if there is a if way for this resolution please tell me, i want to try and learn all possible ways to do it.
Thank you.
Working code with try:

```html
    public void OnButtonClick(View ver) {

        //Atribuir as caixas de texto a varariavel
        EditText et1 = findViewById(R.id.et1);
        EditText et2 = findViewById(R.id.et2);
        TextView tv1 = findViewById(R.id.tv1);

        float input1;
        float input2;
        //Atribui o conteudo das ET para as variaveis e faz/apresenta a soma
        try {
            input1 = Float.parseFloat(et1.getText().toString());
            input2 = Float.parseFloat(et2.getText().toString());
            float sum = input1 + input2;
            tv1.setText(String.valueOf(sum));

        }
        catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
            //Se estiver vazio msg de erro
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Vazio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
}
```